# C++ OpenCV Source

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I have downloaded OpenCV. I have got the demos working but what I really want to do is step throuh the source code and see what is going on.

In C# I download source code and set it up so that I can step through it but I do not know how to do this or even if it is possible in C++.  I do not even know how to set the source code up so that I can right click on a method name and then click go to definition.

Is it possible to do the same things with source code in C++ as in C#, if so how do I do this?

Comment: Presumably this is on Windows ? OpenCV is cross-platform so you might want to tag your post appropriately if it's Windows-specific.

Comment: Were you able to compile and run it and just stuck on the debug thing? Or you couldn't even compile it? Please give more details.

Comment: I can compile and run the demos.  For example I can step through the code in the cpp files that are in the demo project but as soon as I get a call to a method that I assume is contained in a compiled dll I cannot step into it.  I want to know how to step into it using the source like you can in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want the IDE to show the source code while debugging, or when you click something like "go to declaration" or "follow object under cursor". You will need to tell the IDE where to find the source code.

The Windows OpenCV installer includes the source code, so if you want to locate it manually, check where the installer installs its magic. In Visual Studio, you can add source directories to the Environment in Preferences.

Comment: In property pages for the project there is: Configuration Properties>VC++ Directories>Source Directories which has been automatically filled in with the location of the source.  How do I set things so that I can just press F11 and step into this source as need be?

Comment: (I don't use VS) Normally I would think that if you have an OpenCV include somewhere in the source file, and F11 is the "go to source/definition" button I meant, it should work. If this doesn't work, I can't help you further, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [OpenCV 2.2 for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe/download) (with VS 2010 project).

> OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe
>
> installation package containing OpenCV source code,
>     documentation, samples and pre-compiled
>     32-bit binaries for Visual Studio 2010 developers.
>     It does not contain 64-bit binaries, binaries
>     for other compilers, such as VS2008 or MinGW.
>     It does not have TBB or IPP support built-in.
>     If you need those, reconfigure and rebuild OpenCV from the source code

Comment: I have the previous version at the moment running in VS2010 on a 64-bit system.  What does the absence of 64-bit binaries mean - will I have difficulty running it on a 64-bit system?  You are saying that it is easier to set things up so that I can step through the source and see what is actually going on in the 2.2 version?

Comment: @descf I'm not sure if 2.1 supports 64-bit that well, and yes, that's what I'm saying.